# Angular 6:services with providedIn: 'root' returns empty object in component

Tags: javascript, angular, service, dependency-injection

My service located in `src/core/services/api.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor() { }

  test() {
    console.log('hello from services');
  }
}
```

I am trying to invoke this service from a component which in another module.

`home.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from './core/services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.api);
  }

}
```

But I am getting an empty object like this `ApiService {}`

Comment: if it's logging `ApiService {}`, then that's an ApiService instance, exactly as intended. You can find the `test` method under the object's prototype. Are you 100% sure this is not working or did you just guess it?

Comment: yeah, right! Check this, this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aizqtq `ApiService` works fine

Comment: Your code is looking and working perfectly fine. No change is needed.

Comment: Additionaly, if you don't want to do any sort of call, just do: `console.log(this.api instanceof ApiService);`, if it logs true, it just works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it is returning an object and that means that the service is initialized correctly, instead of `console.log(this.api)`; try `console.log(this.api.test())`, you should see `hello from services` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened for me in Angular 8.

I added public in front of the function then it started working:

```
public test()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some unused imports in the service.

Removing those imports and restarting **ng serve** worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'ApiService' as a provider into 'app.module.ts'.
In other modules, remove this service from the providers section.
Now the service will be initialized correctly.